# Why can't I remove the default NavLink?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, json, team-sites

After selecting a team site, I choose my design. I want to remove the default navigation so that it is not visible immediately after creating the team site. According to the documentation, I have uploaded the code to my pattern:

```
{
"verb": "removeNavLink",
"displayName": "Conversations",
"isWebRelative": true}, ...
```

Unfortunately, the navigation is not removed, only when I select my design on the existing site again.

Should I add another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `navComponent` property from your `removeNavLink` action. This property is needed so that SharePoint knows which navigation you wish to remove the link from.

[JSON Schema for SiteScript Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/site-design-script-actions.schema.json)

Comment: Hello, in documentation is: navComponent: The component where to remove the link from, QuickLaunch, Hub, or Footer. The default is QuickLaunch. i check for the team site both option and not help that ;)

Comment: That's interesting. Does it resolve the issue if you set it anyway?

Comment: In not resolve. Is work fine on existing sites